# ANDROID - it is possible to getView in simpleAdapter for save value of each ratingBar in listview?

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

I've been tried to find any tutorial or reference from the site to help me for a weeks, and the link ([link1](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/rating-bar-in-listview-android.html) ; [link2](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-vote-rating-php-mysql.html)) tell me to create a `ListViewAdapter` to handle it, but I don't know how to use for now,

so there's a way to save each value of `ratingBar` in `ListView` without making a custom adapter?

if the answer is yes, please give me some code to check it on `Log.d`!

this is a few code of `ListView` `SimpleAdapter` :

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Pertanyaan.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_pertanyaan, new String[]{"ask", "id"}, new int[]{R.id.ask, R.id.txtid});
```

but I don't have an idea to insert the `ratingBar` into the `ListView` and save the value of `ratingBar` through `simpleAdapter`

any suggest or example code how to fix the issue please!

Comment: any help guys?!

Comment: link1 is a pretty good example, why can't you use that?

Comment: @Hahn because it's need to declare the rating first in php thats i don't want, and i need to make it online

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Hahn i have a `TextView` and `RatingBar` in `ListView`, then i want to know how to send any rating that has a star to server with php script

Comment: you need to atleast override getView() function and put the code to save ratings to webservice in there